# Python: Errno 38 - Function not implemented on open file

Tags: python

I have a function which is supposed to take several arguments and print them to a file. My code is as follows:

```
def write_new(self, filename, file_size, md5, description, data, timestamp):
    if (isfile(self.Filename)):
        print ('IS FILE')
        return False
    ip, port = data
    data = '\n'.join( str(s) for s in [ filename, file_size, FileStream.CHUNK_SIZE_DEFAULT,
        md5, description, FileStream.build_peer(ip, port, True, int(file_size + 0.5 / FileStream.CHUNK_SIZE_DEFAULT), int(timestamp)) ] )
    with open(self.Filename, 'w') as F:
        F.write(data)
    return True

def build_peer(ip, port, full_or_empty, size, timestamp):
    return ':'.join( str(s) for s in [ip, port, '0,' + str(size), '1' if full_or_empty else '0', timestamp] )
```

I called this once successfully and it created a file with the appropriate values. I then deleted the file and tried to create it again and I got an Errno 38, Function not implemented and then listed my file as a function. I'm not sure what is going on and some help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't capitalize attribute names such as `Filename` unless they are a type, it's confusing. And try to break your lines in logical chunks, it's very hard to read as is. And use `format()` for formatting strings, building a heterogenous list just for the purpose of formatting with `join` is both awkward and hard to read.

Comment: By the way for your actual problem, what's the filename you are trying to use, which system are you using it on and what's the full stack trace, or at least the part relevant to the error you are getting?

Comment: You have `if (isfile(self.Filename)):`, but it looks like what you would really want there is `if (isfile(filename)):`, because you've already passed a parameter into the function called `filename`.  You do the same thing a few more lines down at `with open(self.Filename, 'w') as F:` but I'm pretty sure you still want to use simply `filename`.

Comment: @coralv `self.Filename` has a directory constant and extension attached to it. The actual value `filename` is used for printing purposes only.

Comment: @spectras I've tested this with several file names, usually of the form `x.track`. I'm using it on Linux and I don't have access to the full stack trace.

Comment: Can you create the file manually using `touch x.track` in the same location? Errno 38 could be caused by a path too long for the filesystem.

Comment: @spectras I got an error; cannot touch `x.track`: Function not implemented

Comment: So the issue is not from your program. Most probably you are trying to write in a deep directory and the full path is too long for the filesystem you are using.

Comment: @spectras But that doesn't make sense because the file was created in that directory. The directory is `/usr/local/home/rwwwc2/SDRIVE/CS 5600/Project/server/torrents`

Comment: Is that a flash drive? Formatted with FAT or VFAT?

Comment: Can you create manually the file? Is it possible that you do not have like right permission with the current user in that folder? Last but not least why is Filename capitalize?

Comment: @spectras It's not a flash drive; it's located on a network-shared drive at a university with a highly incompetent IT department, probably FAT

Comment: If it's an old kind of FAT, it would not support extensions with more than 3 characters. Seems far fetched nowadays, but can you try with a filename such as `x.trk`?

Comment: Now that you fixed it, if you're interested, I had made [this gist](https://gist.github.com/spectras/a852d3077d88183b34380f991243b3c7) with a cleaned up version of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was IT's fault. I didn't have permissions to delete the file from that network share drive. I would advise against trusting IT in the future.

Comment: So you were seeing it as deleted, but it was not actually deleted? Okay, well, 38 (not implemented) is an odd error code for that behavior. Nice to see you solved you issue.

Comment: @spectras I deleted it from Windows, probably had something to do with it. Sorry for your trouble

Comment: No worries, glad you fixed it. And leave the question around, it might come in handy to other people that stumble upon the same issue :)